# IBM WebSphere Application server SOAP connector issue

Tags: soap, websphere, soap-client, pkix

**Can anyone please help me to fix the below issue ,we are connecting to WebSphere application server with the SOAP connector port 8884 ,every day we will restart the server ,
but we are getting the below error randomly after we restart the server ,then it will start to work next day server restart**

```
com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorException: ADMC0016E: The system cannot create a SOAP connector to connect to host MYDP01 at port 8884.
        at com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory.createAdminClientPrivileged(AdminClientFactory.java:635)
        at com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory.access$000(AdminClientFactory.java:127)
        at com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory$1.run(AdminClientFactory.java:210)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:63)
        at com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory.createAdminClient(AdminClientFactory.java:206)
        at com.myapp.websphere.MyAppWebSphereThread.run(MyAppWebSphereThread.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor75.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:437)
        at com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory.createAdminClientPrivileged(AdminClientFactory.java:457)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorNotAvailableException: [SOAPException: faultCode=SOAP-ENV:Client; msg=Error opening socket: java.io.IOException: Exception during sslSocket.startHandshake: PKIX path building failed: com.ibm.security.cert.IBMCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; targetException=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error opening socket: java.io.IOException: Exception during sslSocket.startHandshake: PKIX path building failed: com.ibm.security.cert.IBMCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target]
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.reconnect(SOAPConnectorClient.java:437)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.<init>(SOAPConnectorClient.java:236)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: [SOAPException: faultCode=SOAP-ENV:Client; msg=Error opening socket: java.io.IOException: Exception during sslSocket.startHandshake: PKIX path building failed: com.ibm.security.cert.IBMCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; targetException=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error opening socket: java.io.IOException: Exception during sslSocket.startHandshake: PKIX path building failed: com.ibm.security.cert.IBMCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target]
        at org.apache.soap.transport.http.SOAPHTTPConnection.send(SOAPHTTPConnection.java:475)
        at org.apache.soap.rpc.Call.WASinvoke(Call.java:510)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient$4.run(SOAPConnectorClient.java:395)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.reconnect(SOAPConnectorClient.java:380)
        ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just checked,
Please do the next step below as the instructions:

1. Check and edit in Web Admin Console

   Application servers View more information about this page   Expand or collapse
   Application servers > Server1TPEXSrv01 > Ports > ***SOAP_CONNECTOR_ADDRESS***
   Specifies the TCP/IP ports this server uses for connections.

   Configuration
   Information required Host
   uat-tpx02
   Information required Port
2. In Server file

You below as the line and check and EDIT SOAP Connector Addresss

> /uat2app/TPEXSrv10/config/cells/server1Cell10/nodes/server1TPEXNode10/serverindex.xml

Thanks and regards

tandn